# Docker volume does not produce file in local-system

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-run

I'm new to docker volumes and trying my best to process the file in docker and save the file in local directory to sync it to AWS S3.

Here is my docker-run command with `--volume` which is using local-directory path attaching it to container. When i run the command on my local system(MacOS). It creates a file in local-directory(`created_file.txt`)

```
docker run -v /*/test_image:/src -t test python3 test_script.py --pick_path=/src/image_lenna.jpeg
```

Here is the same docker-run command on my EC2 instance

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/test_file/test_image:/src -t test python3 test_script.py --pick_path=/src/image_lenna.jpeg
```

The output in local system:

[image: LocalSystem]

The output in remote system:

[image: RemoteSystem]

The Dockerfile contents

```
FROM nginx

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y curl
RUN apt-get install unzip
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
USER root
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "libsm6", "libxext6", "libxrender-dev"]


WORKDIR .
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY test_script.py .
RUN echo "hello world"
```

The command that I used to generate the docker file is:

```
docker build -t test .
```

`.` refers to the folder where my `Dockerfile` resides

I'm not getting why the file is not getting created on EC2 instance. Am I missing something?

Comment: What's your image's `CMD`?  Can you include the code that generates the two image files you attached?

Comment: It is simple build command. I have included

Answer (score 0):

This was kinda silly mistake. The write path in the python script should also be the path that is mentioned for docker volume.

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/test_file/test_image:/src -t test python3 test_script.py --pick_path=/src/image_lenna.jpeg
```

Here the local path is attached to `docker volume` named `src`. So the python script should write to `src` folder.